# Error deploying with heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

My app works without a problem on my localhost but I can't get it to deploy correctly with heroku.  I have read through all the other questions about this here and tried many ways to resolve it but have not managed yet.

I have copied my heroku log below as I cannot work out how to solve this.

```
2013-02-12T16:57:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2013-02-12T16:57:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2013-02-12T16:57:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
2013-02-12T16:57:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
2013-02-12T16:57:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-02-12T16:57:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
2013-02-12T16:57:40+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': superclass mismatch for class UsersController (TypeError)
2013-02-12T16:57:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2013-02-12T16:57:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2013-02-12T16:57:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2013-02-12T16:57:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2013-02-12T16:57:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2013-02-12T16:57:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2013-02-12T16:57:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2013-02-12T16:57:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2013-02-12T16:57:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-02-12T16:57:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2013-02-12T16:57:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `require'
2013-02-12T16:57:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2013-02-12T16:57:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
2013-02-12T16:57:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
2013-02-12T16:57:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2013-02-12T16:57:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
2013-02-12T16:57:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2013-02-12T16:57:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2013-02-12T16:57:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2013-02-12T16:57:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2013-02-12T16:57:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2013-02-12T16:57:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2013-02-12T16:57:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2013-02-12T16:57:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2013-02-12T16:57:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2013-02-12T16:57:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2013-02-12T16:57:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2013-02-12T16:57:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2013-02-12T16:57:41+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-02-12T16:57:41+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-02-12T16:57:41+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-02-12T16:57:48+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 8575`
2013-02-12T16:58:03+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-02-12T16:58:03+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.10 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:8575
2013-02-12T16:58:03+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2013-02-12T16:58:03+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-02-12T16:58:03+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-02-12T16:58:03+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-02-12T16:58:06+00:00 app[web.1]:         provide a secret to prevent exploits that may be possible from crafted
2013-02-12T16:58:06+00:00 app[web.1]:         cookies. This will not be supported in future versions of Rack, and
2013-02-12T16:58:06+00:00 app[web.1]:         SECURITY WARNING: No secret option provided to Rack::Session::Cookie.
2013-02-12T16:58:06+00:00 app[web.1]:         This poses a security threat. It is strongly recommended that you
2013-02-12T16:58:06+00:00 app[web.1]:         future versions will even invalidate your existing user cookies.
2013-02-12T16:58:06+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-02-12T16:58:06+00:00 app[web.1]:         Called from: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:28:in `initialize'.
2013-02-12T16:58:06+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': superclass mismatch for class UsersController (TypeError)
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1
/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `require'
2013-02-12T16:58:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2013-02-12T16:58:11+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-02-12T16:58:11+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-02-12T16:58:13+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=guidelines.herokuapp.com fwd=122.149.95.138 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-02-12T16:58:14+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=guidelines.herokuapp.com fwd=122.149.95.138 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

My admin usercontroller.rb is

```
class Admin::UserController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
  def new
  end
end
```

Comment: `superclass mismatch for class UsersController (TypeError)` 

Can you share the class definition of `UsersController`? If this works locally, it suggests you may have code changes that are not committed, or have not pushed them to Heroku.

Comment: thanks - have copied it above...

Comment: it's  saying UsersController but my controller is called UserController.  I changed the name previously to avoid this error - where would it be getting the UsersController name from?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an `Admin` Module or Class? I've setup similar controllers like so:

`admin_controller.rb` in the `controllers/` folder:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  ...
end
```

and then a sub controller for Users in `controllers/admin/users_controller.rb`:

```
class Admin::UsersController < AdminController
  def index
  end
  def new
  end
end
```

Then in your routes you scope or namespace appropriately:

```
#routes.rb
namespace :admin
    resource :users
end
```

See ["Controller Namespaces and Routing"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) for the specific routing you need.

Comment: Thanks but I'm still getting the same error. The error says UsersController but my controller is called UserController. I changed the name previously to avoid this error - where would it be getting the UsersController name from?

Comment: a resource `users` needs a `users` controller, in file `controllers/users_controller.rb` (or a subfolder). This is a Ruby on Rails convention.

Comment: Thanks - I have now added a user_controller.rb but am still getting the exact same error message

Answer (score 0):

Thanks - I managed to resolve this.

I had a conflict with an unnecessary user_controller.rb in an admin folder when I was using activeadmin.

All solved.